# Is it possible to assign the return value of different functions that return different structs (that implement a common trait) to a single variable?

Tags: rust, polymorphism, traits

Let's say I have something like this:

```rust
trait SomeTrait {}

struct One;
impl SomeTrait for One {}
struct Two;
impl SomeTrait for Two {}

fn return_one() -> One {
    One
}

fn return_two() -> Two {
    Two
}
```

Somewhere else, I want to essentially do:

```rust
fn do_stuff(op: Operation) {
    let result = match op {
        Operation::OpOne => return_one(),
        Operation::OpTwo => return_two(),
    };
}
```

That of course doesn't compile, as those two `return_*()` functions return distinct types.    I've tried:

- Declaring `result` as `dyn SomeTrait` (still `error: mismatched types`)
- Casting the return values, e.g. `return_one() as dyn SomeTrait`  (`error: cast to unsized type: One as dyn SomeTrait`)
- Making `Sized` a supertrait of `SomeTrait` (this won't work for me in this particular case as I don't have control over the real-world version of `SomeTrait`, but it doesn't compile anyway: `error: the trait SomeTrait cannot be made into an object`

Things I think would work but don't want to or can't do:

- Boxing values on return, e.g. `Box::new(return_one()) as dyn Box<SomeTrait>` (having to move the values into a box, and thus off the stack, seems excessive)
- Having `return_one()` and `return_two()` instead return `impl SomeTrait` (this would allow me to accidentally return `Two` from `return_one()`, for example, and I want to use the type system to prevent that)
- Wrapping with an enum: I don't want the functions to return a wrapper enum, because then we have the same problem as the previous bullet point.  I could wrap the return values in an enum at the call site, and that could work, but let's say there's some function on SomeTrait that I want to call at the end; it seems like a lot of extra boilerplate to then unwrap the enum and call that function for each inner type.  If I were to do that, I might as well just copy-paste the trait function call to each match arm.
- I found a few crates on crates.io that claim to be able to do this, but AFAICT they all require implementing a trait on the types, which are foreign types for me, so I can't do that.

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: @Stargateur I don't want to return the enumeration from the functions for the same reason I don't want to return `impl SomeTrait`.  But ok, I could wrap them _after_ the return, but then I'd just have to unwrap them later, when all I want to do is call a method on the trait.  I might as well just copy-paste the method call to each match arm if I'm going to do that...  Will edit to reflect this, though

Comment: your question make less and less sense, what is `Operation` ? you function doesn't return anything, you don't show anywhere the function come from your trait.

Comment: @Stargateur I think it makes perfect sense, and throwing "various reasons" as the justification isn't very helpful.  The goal here is to write concise code; wrapping the return values in an enum does the opposite of that, and makes the trait itself pretty pointless.

Comment: if you want to write concise code don't choice Rust I guess. various reason => first result on duckduckgo https://www.mattkennedy.io/blog/rust_polymorphism/

Comment: @Stargateur This isn't the actual code; I've reduced it to something easy to read and digest.  Please understand that we don't have an instance of the "XY Problem" here; I do actually want to do this, and am merely trying to find out if it's possible.  If it's not, please just say so.

Comment: @Stargateur ok, thanks for the dismissive "help", I guess.

Comment: well, it's hard to help you much, what I would do in your case if I understand correctly what you try here is having two different code in my match branch.

Answer (score 2):

A possible option is to do the following

```rust
fn do_stuff(op: Operation) {
    let (one, two);
    let _result: &dyn SomeTrait = match op {
        Operation::OpOne => {one = return_one(); &one},
        Operation::OpTwo => {two = return_two(); &two},
    };
}
```

You can also use `&mut dyn SomeTrait` instead if you need to borrow it mutably.

This is somewhat verbose, but if you find yourself doing it a lot, a macro
that declares the anonymous variables, assigns them and returns a reference might help.

Another solution could be to use the [auto_enums](https://docs.rs/auto_enums) crate, which automaticaly creates the enum and implements the trait for it, the downside is that it only supports certain traits, (mostly in `std`, I believe) and that for this specific use case it requires nightly, or putting the `match` in a separate function.
I'm not sure I can link a specific part of the docs, but if you scroll down to "#Rust Nightly", you'll see your specific use of it, something like as follows

```rust
use auto_enums::auto_enum;

fn do_stuff(op: Operation) {
    #[auto_enum(SomeTrait)]
    let _result = match op {
        Operation::OpOne => return_one(),
        Operation::OpTwo => return_two(),
    };
}
```

Although keep in mind this only works if `auto_enums` supports `SomeTrait`.

Comment: note that first would result in overheat compare to more straight forward solution.

Comment: @Stargateur what do you mean by overheat? If you mean stack space, then it's likely llvm can optimize it and only reserve as much space as the largest variant, as only one of them will ever be written to, although I haven't tested this.

Comment: this require compiler add at runtine a boolean to know if the variable need to be drop.

Comment: Ah, neat, hadn't thought about that trick. Agree that it gets kinda verbose, but you're right that a macro could make it look nicer (at the expense of having to carry a macro around)

Comment: not to mention the extra dynamic dispatch cost.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does seem the dynamic dispatch cost can't be optimized, as seen [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=f332ebd425d36928aad289b692f84a62), on the 'asm' view, a virtual call is still made even with everything being inline.

Comment: @kelnos I've added another possible solution, I understand you didn't want to use enums, but with this solution it should be transparent, as if enums weren't involved.

Comment: And thanks for the auto_enum pointer.  The trait I'm using isn't supported, unfortunately, but maybe there are some ideas I can use from auto_enum.